# IIS wont run C++ CGI program

Tags: c++, iis

I am having major issues running C++ CGI on IIS. I could have sworn I set it up the same as my last computer (Windows 10 32bit Nextbook 11 Flex) but this one (Windows 10 64bit HP LP1965) I went to Turn Windows Features on, enabled IIS, turned on CGI and filters, and web includes, enabled the handler, and added the application. But I cant seem to be able to run it. Here are the logs

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2017-02-18 16:00:27
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2017-02-18 16:00:27 ::1 GET /chrisandarpitllc/ - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 - 403 14 0 728
2017-02-18 16:00:27 ::1 GET /favicon.ico - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 http://localhost/chrisandarpitllc/ 404 0 2 3
2017-02-18 16:00:36 ::1 GET /chrisandarpitllc/index.exe - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 - 404 2 1260 7
2017-02-18 16:01:58 ::1 GET /chrisandarpitllc/index.exe - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 - 502 2 3221225781 47
2017-02-18 16:05:08 ::1 GET /chrisandarpitllc/index.exe - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 - 502 2 3221225781 12
2017-02-18 16:05:08 ::1 GET /chrisandarpitllc/index.exe - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 - 502 2 3221225781 5
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2017-02-18 16:25:25
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2017-02-18 16:25:25 ::1 GET /chrisandarpitllc/index.exe - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 - 502 2 3221225781 14
2017-02-18 16:26:50 ::1 GET /chrisandarpitllc - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 - 301 0 0 1
2017-02-18 16:26:50 ::1 GET /chrisandarpitllc/ - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 2
2017-02-18 16:26:53 ::1 GET /chrisandarpitllc/index.exe - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 http://localhost/chrisandarpitllc/ 502 2 3221225781 11
2017-02-18 16:28:14 ::1 GET /favicon.ico - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 http://www.chrisandarpitllc.com/ 404 0 2 0
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2017-02-18 16:31:07
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2017-02-18 16:31:07 ::1 GET /chrisandarpitllc/ - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 9
2017-02-18 16:31:10 ::1 GET /chrisandarpitllc/index.exe - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 http://localhost/chrisandarpitllc/ 502 2 3221225781 29
2017-02-18 16:32:08 ::1 GET /chrisandarpitllc/index.exe - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 http://localhost/chrisandarpitllc/ 502 2 3221225781 27
2017-02-18 16:32:08 ::1 GET /chrisandarpitllc/index.exe - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 http://localhost/chrisandarpitllc/ 502 2 3221225781 10
2017-02-18 16:32:08 ::1 GET /chrisandarpitllc/index.exe - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 http://localhost/chrisandarpitllc/ 502 2 3221225781 5
2017-02-18 16:32:08 ::1 GET /chrisandarpitllc/index.exe - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 http://localhost/chrisandarpitllc/ 502 2 3221225781 5
2017-02-18 16:32:13 ::1 GET /chrisandarpitllc/ - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 - 502 2 3221225781 13
2017-02-18 16:32:58 ::1 GET /chrisandarpitllc/ - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 - 502 2 3221225781 19
2017-02-18 16:32:58 ::1 GET /chrisandarpitllc/ - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 - 502 2 3221225781 5
2017-02-18 16:32:58 ::1 GET /chrisandarpitllc/ - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 - 502 2 3221225781 5
2017-02-18 16:32:58 ::1 GET /chrisandarpitllc/ - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 - 502 2 3221225781 13
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2017-02-18 16:46:58
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2017-02-18 16:46:58 ::1 GET /chrisandarpitllc/index.exe - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 - 404 2 1260 663
2017-02-18 16:46:58 ::1 GET /favicon.ico - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 http://localhost/chrisandarpitllc/index.exe 404 0 2 5
2017-02-18 16:50:22 ::1 GET /chrisandarpitllc/index.exe - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 - 404 2 1260 20
2017-02-18 16:52:18 ::1 GET /chrisandarpitllc/index.exe - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 - 502 2 3221225781 90
2017-02-18 16:52:18 ::1 GET /chrisandarpitllc/index.exe - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 - 502 2 3221225781 7
2017-02-18 16:52:18 ::1 GET /chrisandarpitllc/index.exe - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 - 502 2 3221225781 6
2017-02-18 16:58:14 ::1 GET /chrisandarpitllc/ - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 - 502 2 3221225781 29
```

And here is a screenshot of the error

[IIS Error given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rn3BB.png)

And here is the code (Which was a simple test)

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    std::cout << "Content-Type:text/html\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why all this is happening? How can I fix this? If you need any information please let me know and I will provide it.

I also checked the website on another device this is what I got..

[Mobile device error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E51bP.png)

Comment: Whats the down vote for? I followed the rules when posting

Comment: Anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Content-type header may be finished by "\r\n\r\n" symbols